# I can't make Django DeleteView to work

Tags: python, django, django-views

So I was trying to set up a `DeleteView` for my `Lecture` model. Each course from my `Course` model has its own slug page. And on that page lectures for a course appear.

Thing is that I tried to add a delete button for lectures, but it was unsuccessful.

Here is what what I did:

```html
  #courses.html
  
  {% regroup lectures by get_lecture_category_display as category_list %}
        <h3>Lectures</h3>
        <ul>
            {% for category in category_list %}
                <strong>
                    <li>{{ category.grouper }}</li>
                </strong>
                <ul>
                    {% for c in category.list %}
                        .............
                        <li>{{ c.lecture_title }}</li>
                        <li>{{ c.content }}</li>
                        {% for file in c.files.all %}
                            {% if file.files %}
                                <li><a href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ file.files.url }}'>download</a></li>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                       <a href="{% url 'courses:lecture_delete' c.slug %}">Delete</a>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

#lecture_confirm_delete.html

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Are you sure you want to delete?
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm"/>
</form>

#urls.py

    path('<slug:slug>/', views.courses, name='courses'),
    path('<slug:slug>/delete/', views.LectureDelete.as_view(), name='lecture_delete'),


#models.py

class Lecture(models.Model):
    LECTURE_CHOICES = (
        ('Courses', 'Courses'),
        ('Seminars', 'Seminars'),
    )
    course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', related_name='lectures', )
    lecture_category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=LECTURE_CHOICES, default='Courses', )
    lecture_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=False, default=No
 
 
class Course(models.Model):
    study_programme = models.ForeignKey('StudyProgramme', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    ects = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(99)])
    description = models.TextField()
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(99)])
    semester = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, "1"),
                                            (2, "2"),
                                            ), default=None)
    teacher1 = models.ForeignKey('TeacherData', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None,
                                 verbose_name="Course Teacher", related_name='%(class)s_course_teacher')
    teacher2 = models.ForeignKey('TeacherData', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True,
                                 verbose_name="Seminar Teacher", related_name='%(class)s_seminar_teacher')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=140, unique=True)
```

Problem is this:
 If in courses.html link I put `c.slug`, then I get this error: http://dpaste.com/1K1T8N8
 But If I put `c.id` or `c.pk`, then page will show and if I press delete button I get this error:  http://dpaste.com/3TRSJE2

Here is my view:

```html
class LectureDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Lecture
    success_url = reverse_lazy('courses:index')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any field as `slug` in your model.

You just need to do:

```
path('<int:id>/delete/', views.LectureDelete.as_view(), name='lecture_delete'),
```

and in `href`

```
href="{% url 'courses:lecture_delete' c.id %}"
```

Comment: With that path, it requested a pk or a slug so I changed in href to c.pk and in path with int:pk and it worked, it redirected me to lecture_confirm_delete.html but when I press confirm I get this error: http://dpaste.com/0744WFB

Comment: @DannM, try deleting some other and see if it works?

Comment: What the hell :D Others can be deleted. Should I delete the one with issues from admin panel then ?

Comment: You would have tried that one earlier and it may have made it null.

Comment: I see. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Feel glad that it helped. Thanks

Comment: Excuse me, but my database might be corrupted or something ? if I create a new lecture object, apparently, when I try to delete it, I get that error again

Comment: If there is not much relevant data, I will suggest to create the database again.